# Why the output of "open" function doesn't allow me to attribute index?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

I started to learn programming in python3 and i am doing a project that reads the content of a text file and tells you how many words are in the file. Being me I always want to challenge myself and tried to add in the output message the name of the file so in the future I will do a GUI for it and so on.

The error that I get is : AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'index'

Here is my code:

```
# Open text file

document = open("text2.txt", "r+")

# Reads the text file and splits it into arrays
text_split = document.read().split()

# Count the words
words = len(text_split)

# Display the counted words
document_name = document[document.index("name=")]
output = "In the file {} there are {} words.".format(document_name, words)

print (output)
```

Comment: `document` is a file handle. Work on `words` from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to take @Jean-François Fabre 's advice and abandoned the idea to also output the name of the file (FOR NOW).